# how can I store diffrent value types in an array using c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, templates, generic-type-argument

I'm having trouble with some features I want to implement in my config class, I have some values with diffrent types and I want to store them in an map. formerly i used ExtendedString class to store all data and convert them using a template function to the wanted type whenever I needed. and then had a `map<ExtendedString,vector<ExtendedString> >` in my config class to store all the keys in config file. here is what my ExtendedString class already look like:

```
class ExtendedString : public std::string
{
public:
    ExtenedString() : public std::string
    {
    }
    template <class T> ExtenededString(T)
    {
        std::stringstream s;
        *this = s.str();
    }
    template <class T>T as(){
        istringstream s(*this);
        T temp;
        d >> temp;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

now i want to parse all the values while loading my config file and also have the feature of converting to any possible type in case of need. for example if i parsed some value into an int and in my runtime i needed that value as string I want to be able to cast it right away, and besides i prefer not using boost in this case, it's one of my base classes and I don't want to link boost to every project i'm developing.

Comment: I just bought this nifty chainsaw. Can someone tell me how to remove the guard and glue down the safety switch?

Comment: ha? what do mean? are you saying my question is irrelevant?

Comment: You shouldn't inherit from standard library classes. I don't see anything in your `ExtendedString` class that needs to be in a class at all, just use free functions.

Comment: @GMan trying to check if your Idea (or at least what your hint lead me to) can be implemented

Comment: What I mean is that you are, at best, disabling features that are there to prevent mishap. At worst, you are asking for code that has almost human-level intelligence-- how else can it decide, at runtime, how to convert e.g. `set<DateAndTime>` to `map<string, Complex>`?

Comment: @Beta: seems it's not impossible after all! see answers.

Comment: That's fine for types with a defined `operator<<`, which isn't "any possible type". It seems that what you had in mind was easier than what you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/any.html), as it sounds like it does what you are looking for.  However, if you really don't want to use it, you might be able to handle it something like this.  It may not be the best way to do it (its the first thing that came into my head) - basically its storing the value in the type you had it as originally, and as a string.  If you try and `get` it as the original type, it returns that value, otherwise, it will use a `std::stringstream` to try and convert it.

*Note:* This doesn't handle copying/assignment, change `d_data` to your shared pointer of choice to handle that.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class ConfigValue
{
    class HolderBase
    {
      protected:
        virtual void writeValueToStream(std::ostream& os) const = 0;

      public: 
        virtual ~HolderBase() { }

        template <class Type>
        Type getAs() const
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            writeValueToStream(ss);

            Type temp;
            ss >> temp;
            return temp;
        }
    };

    template <class Type>
    class Holder : public HolderBase
    {
        Type d_value;

      protected:
        void writeValueToStream(std::ostream& os) const
        {
            os << d_value;
        }

      public:
        Holder(const Type& value)
        : d_value(value)
        {
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << value;
        }

        Type get() const
        {
            return d_value;
        }
    };

    HolderBase *d_data;

  public:
    template <class Type>
    ConfigValue(const Type& value)
    : d_data(new Holder<Type>(value))
    {
    }

    ~ConfigValue()
    {
        delete d_data;
    }

    template <class Type>
    Type get() const
    {
        if (Holder<Type> *holder = dynamic_cast<Holder<Type>*>(d_data))
        {
            return holder->get();
        }
        else
        {
            return d_data->getAs<Type>();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    ConfigValue cv = 10;

    std::cout << cv.get<std::string>() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your implementation is almost the best thing that came to my head, except do you think it's possible to remove that string value from every type? and by the way boost::any doesn't give any conversion feature if types mismatch so it's not the answer to my solution.

Comment: @Gajet - I have edited the code to remove the `std::string`.  Now, if you try to get it as a type other than the type the data is stored in, it will call an `operator<<` to write it to a `std::stringstream`, then an `operator>>` to convert it to the target type.  That what you meant?

Comment: Dont forget about the copying issue, you either need to use a shared pointer for `d_data`, or implement the copy constructor and `operator==`.  Otherwise you'll run into problems using this in an STL container.

Answer (score 2):

One classic solution is [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/any.html), or a massive `union`.  But I think both of those approaches cause more trouble than they solve.  What's wrong with creating, say, a `Config` class that has member for each configuration option?

Comment: can you provide me with how `boost::any` is implemented?

Comment: @Gajet: boost is open source, here's the implementation of `any`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/any.hpp

Comment: The "`boost::any`" in the answer is a link to the documentation for the library.  "`boost::any`" is essentially a large `union` that includes both primitive types and `void*`.

If you try to store a value in a `boost::any` that is not a primitive type (say, a `std::string`), the value is allocated with `new`, and the pointer to that value is stored in the `union`.  You have to keep track of what you put in the `boost::any` object so you can cast it back correctly.

Comment: I don't like the memory allocation because that's slow and could be avoided.  And I don't like the concept of an object that can contain values of any type, with the programmer responsible for remembering what was last stored.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing them all as strings, you could write a "Value" class and then write subclasses for each kind of value.

Comment: by doing that i need to use virtual template function (to have what functino As does now) and that's not possibleif you know any better way to implement all features i asked, please provide your implementation.